# Skipping Azure ACS home realm discovery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, acs

I've been looking for a way to integrate the Azure ACS home realm discovery page into our ASP.Net MVC5 app login page rather than use the default one hosted on ACS itself.

What I want is something like what is suggested here:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/#comment-126567

I’m building an MVC 5.1 on .Net 4.5.1 Azure Web Role which needs to authenticate users from multiple corporate identity providers – some with AAD, some with ADFS – and the list will grow over time. Initially this has been simple enough to set-up with Azure ACS as the federation provider. It presents a home realm discovery (HRD) page and the flow works.

Things become complicated when I try and follow the instructions for adding the HRD into my login page directly (following the instructions given in the ACS application integration pages using the Home Realm Discovery Metadata Feed and some example HTML + JS). I am able to present the HRD buttons as I would like however I am struggling with wiring the sign in process into the OWIN WsFederation setup, which in my application currently only knows about the ACS WsFederationMetadataUrl.

I’ve currently got this in my ConfigureAuth method:

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsFederationOptions: new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Whr = ".com";
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },
    MetadataAddress = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Authentication.WsFederationMetadataUrl"),
    Wtrealm = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Authentication.Realm"),
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
});
```

Where .com is the domain of one of the IdPs in my ACS which happens to be our own AAD. But this doesn’t work. Can this scenario be made to work? I found one relevant stack post which talks about skipping the home realm discovery with Ws-Federation OWIN Middleware and allows for the Whr parameter to be set via a user action but so far I haven’t been able to get it to work with the Whr hard coded.

[Skipping home realm discovery with Ws-Federation OWIN Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294162/skipping-home-realm-discovery-with-ws-federation-owin-middleware)

I’ve changed the buttons from the example HTML+JS so that they post to the /Account/ExternalLogin controller action and get into the OWIN pipeline that way:

```
// POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string homeRealm, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, homeRealm, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

rather than use a cookie and navigate to the login page at the chosen home realm (as the boiler plate HTML+JS from the ACS does) :

```
// Sets a cookie to remember the chosen identity provider and navigates to it.
function IdentityProviderButtonClicked() {
    SetCookie(this.getAttribute("name"));
    window.location = this.getAttribute("id");
    return false;
}
```