# Set default domain hint (Home Realm Discovery) to skip Azure AD login prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on, openid-connect

### **Scenario**

When an **external** user has logged into our Sharepoint site and they navigate to our web app they are redirected to our Azure AD tenant-full endpoint sign-in page, as they are already authenticated with the Sharepoint site though AzureAD and ADFS they do not have to enter/select a user account and are redirected to the web app.

When an **internal** user navigates to the web app they are directed to our Azure AD’s tenant-full endpoint sing-in page, as they are not authenticated through AzureAD and ADFS they have to enter a username. When the user enters a username *Home Realm Discovery* is preformed and they are redirected to the ADFS server, as they are accessing the web app from the Intranet they are automatically authenticated and redirected back to the web app.

So the internal user can bypass entering a username the `domain_hint` parameter can be supplied and this works correctly however our internal and external users are in different tenants and therefore the domain is different.

Is it possible to set a default `domain_hint` for the case in which a user is not already authenticated?

Using OWIN OpenIdConnect, ASP.Net MVC. The web app is provisioned in AzureAD which is federated with on-premise ADFS.

[Simlar but we do not know the home realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294162/skipping-home-realm-discovery-with-ws-federation-owin-middleware)

Answer (score 6):

This blog post outlines how to use the domain hint: [Skipping the Home Realm Discovery Page in Azure AD](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/)

Basically this way (note the use of the Domain Hint RedirectToIdentityProvider):

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => 
        {                                                        
            context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "mydomain.com"; 
            return Task.FromResult(0); 
        }, 
    }
});
```

Comment: Posted a double answer for some reason.